# Nesting select in select clause take forever to complete

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-5.7

```
Table markclr
=============
  id     int(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  name   varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  color  varchar(255) NOT NULL,
```

```
Table dvcgrp
=============
  id         int(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  name       varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  markclrid  int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
```

```
Table dvc
=============
  id        int(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  name      varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  shrtname  varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  dvceui    varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  dvcgrpid  int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
```

```
Table vhsrdt
=============
  id             int(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  dvcid          int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  dtrcvtm        timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  dtraw          varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  dtdvcnm        varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  dtgtwid        varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  dtport         int NOT NULL,
  dtdr           int NOT NULL,
  dtadr          varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  dtriptype      varchar(255),
  dlatitudedeg   decimal(10,8),
  dlongitudedeg  decimal(11,8),
  dvextgood      int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  dgpscurrent    int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  dignition      int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  ddigin1        int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  ddigin2        int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  ddigout        int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  dheadingdeg    varchar(255),
  dspeedkmph     varchar(255),
  dbatv          varchar(255),
```

Please help me to explain what happen with my query below:

```
select
  dvc1.id,
  dvc1.name as dvcname,
  dvc1.dvceui as dvcdvceui,
  dvc1.shrtname as dvcshrtname,
  markclr.color as markclrcolor,
  (
    select
      tbl1.dtrcvtm
    from vhsrdt as tbl1
    where
      tbl1.dvcid = dvc1.id and
      tbl1.dtrcvtm = (
        select
          max(tbl2.dtrcvtm) as dtrcvtm
        from vhsrdt as tbl2
        where tbl2.dvcid = tbl1.dvcid
      )
  ) as dtrcvtm,
  (
    select
      tbl1.dtgtwid
    from vhsrdt as tbl1
    where
      tbl1.dvcid = dvc1.id and
      tbl1.dtrcvtm = (
        select
          max(tbl2.dtrcvtm) as dtrcvtm
        from vhsrdt as tbl2
        where tbl2.dvcid = tbl1.dvcid
      )
  ) as dtgtwid,
  (
    select
      tbl1.dtriptype
    from vhsrdt as tbl1
    where
      tbl1.dvcid = dvc1.id and
      tbl1.dtrcvtm = (
        select
          max(tbl2.dtrcvtm) as dtrcvtm
        from vhsrdt as tbl2
        where tbl2.dvcid = tbl1.dvcid
      )
  ) as dtriptype,
  (
    select
      tbl1.dlatitudedeg
    from vhsrdt as tbl1
    where
      tbl1.dvcid = dvc1.id and
      tbl1.dtrcvtm = (
        select
          max(tbl2.dtrcvtm) as dtrcvtm
        from vhsrdt as tbl2
        where tbl2.dvcid = tbl1.dvcid
      )
  ) as dlatitudedeg,
  (
    select
      tbl1.dlongitudedeg
    from vhsrdt as tbl1
    where
      tbl1.dvcid = dvc1.id and
      tbl1.dtrcvtm = (
        select
          max(tbl2.dtrcvtm) as dtrcvtm
        from vhsrdt as tbl2
        where tbl2.dvcid = tbl1.dvcid
      )
  ) as dlongitudedeg,
  (
    select
      tbl1.dspeedkmph
    from vhsrdt as tbl1
    where
      tbl1.dvcid = dvc1.id and
      tbl1.dtrcvtm = (
        select
          max(tbl2.dtrcvtm) as dtrcvtm
        from vhsrdt as tbl2
        where tbl2.dvcid = tbl1.dvcid
      )
  ) as dspeedkmph,
  (
    select
      tbl1.dheadingdeg
    from vhsrdt as tbl1
    where
      tbl1.dvcid = dvc1.id and
      tbl1.dtrcvtm = (
        select
          max(tbl2.dtrcvtm) as dtrcvtm
        from vhsrdt as tbl2
        where tbl2.dvcid = tbl1.dvcid
      )
  ) as dheadingdeg
from dvc as dvc1
left join dvcgrp on dvcgrp.id = dvc1.dvcgrpid
left join markclr on markclr.id = dvcgrp.markclrid
```

The table vhsrdt filled with about 90K data.
If i simulate the database and ran that query on my dev environment using XAMPP it fetch successfully less than 1 sec.
But if i ran that query on production using linux server with MySQL 5.7 it never complete.

I also have tried to delete database and construct all structure and data again but it still cannot complete the query.

Thank you for your help.

Result for `EXPLAIN`:

```
id | select_type        | table    | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                                                                                                               | key                               | key_len | ref                     | rows | filtered | Extra
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | PRIMARY            | dvc1     |            | ALL    |                                                                                                                                                                                                                             |                                   |         |                         | 50   | 100      |
1  | PRIMARY            | dvcgrp   |            | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                                                                     | PRIMARY                           | 4       | klksensor.dvc1.dvcgrpid | 1    | 100      |
1  | PRIMARY            | markclr  |            | ALL    | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |                                   |         |                         | 5    | 100      | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
14 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | tbl1     |            | ref    | vhsrdt_dvcid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtgtwid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtriptype_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlongitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_dlongitudedeg_index | vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index | 4       | klksensor.dvc1.id       | 1627 | 100      | Using where
15 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | tbl2     |            | ref    | vhsrdt_dvcid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtgtwid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtriptype_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlongitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_dlongitudedeg_index | vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index | 4       | klksensor.tbl1.dvcid    | 1627 | 100      | Using index
12 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | tbl1     |            | ref    | vhsrdt_dvcid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtgtwid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtriptype_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlongitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_dlongitudedeg_index | vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index | 4       | klksensor.dvc1.id       | 1627 | 100      | Using where
13 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | tbl2     |            | ref    | vhsrdt_dvcid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtgtwid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtriptype_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlongitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_dlongitudedeg_index | vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index | 4       | klksensor.tbl1.dvcid    | 1627 | 100      | Using index
10 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | tbl1     |            | ref    | vhsrdt_dvcid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtgtwid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtriptype_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlongitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_dlongitudedeg_index | vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index | 4       | klksensor.dvc1.id       | 1627 | 100      | Using where
11 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | tbl2     |            | ref    | vhsrdt_dvcid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtgtwid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtriptype_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlongitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_dlongitudedeg_index | vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index | 4       | klksensor.tbl1.dvcid    | 1627 | 100      | Using index
8  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | tbl1     |            | ref    | vhsrdt_dvcid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtgtwid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtriptype_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlongitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_dlongitudedeg_index | vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index | 4       | klksensor.dvc1.id       | 1627 | 100      | Using where
9  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | tbl2     |            | ref    | vhsrdt_dvcid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtgtwid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtriptype_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlongitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_dlongitudedeg_index | vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index | 4       | klksensor.tbl1.dvcid    | 1627 | 100      | Using index
6  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | tbl1     |            | ref    | vhsrdt_dvcid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtgtwid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtriptype_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlongitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_dlongitudedeg_index | vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index | 4       | klksensor.dvc1.id       | 1627 | 100      | Using where
7  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | tbl2     |            | ref    | vhsrdt_dvcid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtgtwid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtriptype_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlongitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_dlongitudedeg_index | vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index | 4       | klksensor.tbl1.dvcid    | 1627 | 100      | Using index
4  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | tbl1     |            | ref    | vhsrdt_dvcid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtgtwid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtriptype_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlongitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_dlongitudedeg_index | vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index | 4       | klksensor.dvc1.id       | 1627 | 100      | Using where
5  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | tbl2     |            | ref    | vhsrdt_dvcid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtgtwid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtriptype_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlongitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_dlongitudedeg_index | vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index | 4       | klksensor.tbl1.dvcid    | 1627 | 100      | Using index
2  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | tbl1     |            | ref    | vhsrdt_dvcid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtgtwid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtriptype_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlongitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_dlongitudedeg_index | vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index | 4       | klksensor.dvc1.id       | 1627 | 100      | Using where; Using index
3  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | tbl2     |            | ref    | vhsrdt_dvcid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtgtwid_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dtriptype_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlongitudedeg_index,vhsrdt_dvcid_dlatitudedeg_dlongitudedeg_index | vhsrdt_dvcid_dtrcvtm_dtport_index | 4       | klksensor.tbl1.dvcid    | 1627 | 100      | Using index
```

Comment: Type `EXPLAIN` on top of the query and re-run. Then post the `EXPLAIN` result into your question. Another thing, are your tables storing repeated ids?

Comment: @tcadidot0 I have update my question

Comment: Explain clearly indicates that lots of subqueries are running.. what is your MySQL server version ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya MySQL version is 5.7.

Comment: In my question above, i say that that query execute fast on development environment. I just notice that i'm using MariaDB on XAMPP.  
Why MariaDB execute very faster than MySQL

Comment: You cannot compare production to local dev, because production has other things also happening, such as concurrent load from other client sessions. Still, you can run `EXPLAIN` on the local dev server and compare if there any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `EXPLAIN` statement, you can see that lots of **Dependent Subquery** are running; although in your case, all of them are similar with just a difference of `SELECT`ing a difference field. Unfortunately, MySQL does not allow returning a tuple when using a subquery in the `SELECT` clause.

You can reduce all these subqueries to a single subquery, by computing all the `MAX()` values in a single "run", by using in the `FROM` clause. Try the following query instead:

```sql
select
  dvc1.id,
  dvc1.name as dvcname,
  dvc1.dvceui as dvcdvceui,
  dvc1.shrtname as dvcshrtname,
  markclr.color as markclrcolor,
  vhsrdt.dtrcvtm,
  vhsrdt.dtgtwid,
  vhsrdt.dtriptype,
  vhsrdt.dlatitudedeg,
  vhsrdt.dlongitudedeg,
  vhsrdt.dspeedkmph,
  vhsrdt.dheadingdeg
from dvc as dvc1
left join dvcgrp on dvcgrp.id = dvc1.dvcgrpid
left join markclr on markclr.id = dvcgrp.markclrid
left join vhsrdt on vhsrdt.dvcid = dvc1.id 
left join (select max(dtrcvtm) as max_dtrcvtm, dvcid
           from vhsrdt 
           group by dvcid
          ) as dt on dt.dvcid = vhsrdt.dvcid 
                     and dt.max_dtrcvtm = vhsrdt.dtrcvtm
```

Above approach has a limitation of computing `max()` value for all the `dvcid`, whether we need it or not. Moreover, it will lead to temp table creation (in-memory if small, else on disk). Thankfully, MySQL 8.0.14 has introduced [`LATERAL` Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lateral-derived-tables.html); so if you can upgrade to the latest MySQL version, more *performant* query would be:

```sql
select
  dvc1.id,
  dvc1.name as dvcname,
  dvc1.dvceui as dvcdvceui,
  dvc1.shrtname as dvcshrtname,
  markclr.color as markclrcolor,
  v1.dtrcvtm,
  v1.dtgtwid,
  v1.dtriptype,
  v1.dlatitudedeg,
  v1.dlongitudedeg,
  v1.dspeedkmph,
  v1.dheadingdeg
from dvc as dvc1
left join dvcgrp on dvcgrp.id = dvc1.dvcgrpid
left join markclr on markclr.id = dvcgrp.markclrid
left join vhsrdt v1 on v1.dvcid = dvc1.id 
left join lateral (select max(v2.dtrcvtm) as max_dtrcvtm
                   from vhsrdt v2 
                   where v2.dvcid = v1.dvcid
                  ) as dt on dt.max_dtrcvtm = v1.dtrcvtm
```

Comment: I have accept your solution. Your query not fully satisfied my need. But I used your idea with some changes. Thank you.

Comment: @ZemmyIndrapatih what changes you did ? My query replicates what your original query doing